# Accessing property value in linq query table variable

Tags: linq, iqueryable

I have a listbox that is being bound to a linq query variable and all is fine and good there.  I have display member set to show the name, and value member is the GUID id associated to that name.  On selection of a name from that listbox, I want to query another table (one to one) and get the data from it based on the SelectedValue (guid id).  However, when I ask for the selectedValue, it returns the entity name and not the field in the underlying table.  How can I access that field and assign that value to a GUID variable?

Thanks for the information

[Screen shot of table and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXMTG.png)

PS - this is in Visual Basic .Net

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code, its not clear from the screenshot what you are trying to do. What Type is lbForReview?

Comment: Actually I resolved the issue.  I used another LINQ statement to query the iqueryable table.